# I am trying to create authentication system in Django. My code is failing to authenticate the user

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication

```
        <form method="post" action="/" class="mb-2">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Your Username" Required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pass1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass1" name="pass1" placeholder="Enter Your Password" Required>
            </div>
    
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
        </form>
```

This is the form from home.html

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('pass1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, pass1=pass1)
        if user is not None:
             login(request, user)
             return render(request,"main_tem/room.html")
        else:
             return redirect('signup')
    return render(request,"main_tem/home.html")
```

this is home view from views.py in 'main' app.

so as u can see from the home view if user is present or signuped it should redirect user to room.html page but when i try to do it it redirects to signup page which shouldnt happen if user is already present in data base. i am kind of lost here as i dont know what kind of solution i should search for. from what i have observed i think home view is not able to get data from the form in home.html

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
             path("",views.home,name="home"),
             path("signup",views.signup,name="signup"),
             path("rooms",views.rooms,name="rooms"),

            ]
```

for reference here is the urls.py from 'main' app

Comment: I am sorry since now in a hurry don't have time to slice all your code but here's a link to my repo that sorted out the case of creating django auth from scratches https://github.com/carloocchiena/django_auth

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('pass1')
        user = authenticate(username=username, pass1=pass1)
        if user is not None:
             login(request, user)
             return render(request,"main_tem/room.html")
        else:
             return redirect('signup')
    return render(request,"main_tem/home.html")
```

to this:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('pass1')
        auth = authenticate(username=username, password=pass1)
        if auth:
            login(request, auth)
            return render(request,"main_tem/room.html")
        else:
             return redirect('signup')
    return render(request,"main_tem/home.html")
```

You should be go to go.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply i havent tried it but is there a need to import any module in views.py

Comment: Yes, import the following.....      from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout